# Pushing long commit message gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I have problem with gerrit. I want to push a branch to gerrit with long history commits.

The problem that the commit messages are too long and it causes data Base crash when i push the branch.

I'm not sure if the problem is, the commit messages are too long or they contain special characters that are part of data base syntax.

I try 'git reset --soft noCommit' and I reset to the 5th first commit. It solves the problem, but when i update the branch, The history commit meesages returns back and i can not push any more to gerrit.

I'm looking for a solution for this problem. I can not change the commit messages.
How i can change the database settings to accept the long commit message?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the commit messages, do you want to push the commits for review at all?  You may prefer to push them to gerrit bypassing review.

Short of that - we need more details on what is going wrong (server logs)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try bypassing review and i give u more details.

Comment: Good I'm glad it helped.  If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the best answer.